# MATLAB - How to get number of occurences of each word in a string?

Tags: string, matlab

Suppose we want to check how many times any word occurs in a particular text file through MATLAB , How do we do that ? 
Now, since i'm checking for the word to be a SPAM word or a HAM word(doing Content filtering),i'm looking to find the probability of the word to be spam i.e n(no. of spam occurrences)/n(total occurrences) would give the probability.

Hints ?

Comment: Can we assume that the text file has been imported into a string? Or that the words are already separated in a cell array of strings?

Comment: not cell array of strings, consider it has been imported from a text file

Comment: Well you can import as cell arrays or char arrays.

Comment: Problem is i do not know how to , extremely sorry

Comment: "imported from a text file" into what type of variable?

Answer (score 3):

As an example, consider a text file called `text.txt` containing the following text:

> These two sentences, like all sentences, contain words. Some of those words are repeated; but not all.

A possible approach is as follows:

```
s = importdata('text.txt'); %// import text. Gives a 1x1 cell containing a string
words = regexp([lower(s{1}) '.'], '[\s\.,;:-''"?!/()]+', 'split'); %// split 
%// into words. Make sure there's always at least a final punctuation sign.
%// You may want to extend the list of separators (between the brackets)
%// I have made this case insensitive using "lower"
words = words(1:end-1); %// remove last "word", which will always be empty
[uniqueWords, ~, intLabels] = unique(words); %// this is the important part:
%// get unique words and an integer label for each one
count = histc(intLabels, 1:numel(uniqueWords)); %// occurrences of each label
```

The result is `uniqueWords` and `count`:

```
uniqueWords = 
    'all'    'are'    'but'    'contain'    'like'    'not'    'of'    'repeated'
    'sentences'    'some'    'these'    'those'    'two'    'words'    

count =
      2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use regular expressions to find the number of occurrence of a word..

For example:

```
txt = fileread( fileName );
tokens = regexp( txt, string, 'tokens' );
```

String is the one you are searching for..

Comment: can that string be all cells in cellarray of strings one at a time ? That's what i'm looking for i guess then

Comment: @PriyamSoneji - Yes it can.  `regexp` works by either using a single string, or a cell array of strings.

Comment: BTW This is half an answer. You have the right mechanism for searching for specific patterns in strings.  You don't have the logic to count how many times the words occur.  Still, a good push in the right direction.